# HTML::FormHandler roles vs fields

Tags: perl, forms, moose, catalyst

I'm using [HTML::FormHandler](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::FormHandler), and in an effort to not repeat a lot of code I am trying to split my form up into reuasable pieces as suggested by the [HTML::FormHandler Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/module/GSHANK/HTML-FormHandler-0.40020/lib/HTML/FormHandler/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Split-up-your-forms-into-reusable-pieces). It discusses being able to create your own fields or your own roles to accomplish this, however I cannot really a clearcut difference between the two. I understand that they are different in how you implement/use them, but as far as I can tell they seem to pretty similarly accomplish the same things. My question is are there any situations where it is a clear choice to use one over the other? Or is this something that tends to be more a preference kind of thing? Thanks for the help. I'd like to do this right before the code is in production and it's harder to change later :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Moose classes the other is to use Moose roles.

The concepts are slightly different. Here is a snippet from the [Moose Roles manual](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0604/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod):

> A role encapsulates some piece of behavior or state that can be shared
>   between classes. It is something that classes do. It is important to
>   understand that roles are not classes. You cannot inherit from a role,
>   and a role cannot be instantiated. We sometimes say that roles are
>   consumed, either by classes or other roles.

Classes let you use inheritance, roles are good when you want to share functionality without inheriting.

For a (contrived) example of when you would/would not want to use inheritance, see this article on [Roles vs Inheritance](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/05/perl-roles-versus-inheritance.html)